# Define request body property @Body('property) as optional

Tags: nestjs, union-types

I use NestJS and the class-validator package.

In the following function a user should be created. You should have the option to add a booking to the request.

```
@Post()
async create(@Body('user') userToCreate: createUserDTO, @Body('booking') bookingToCreate: createBookingDTO | undefined): Promise<User> {
    return await this.usersService.create(userToCreate, bookingToCreate);
  }
```

If the request has no "booking" field, its value is `undefined`. 
I have confirmed this with `typeof req.body.booking === 'undefined'`.

Instead of accepting `'undefined'` as a valid value, the global ValidationPipe calls the class-validator and complains that booking does not match createBookingDTO - logically.

How can I mark the @Body as optional so that the validation is skipped if the value does not exist and is therefore `'undefined'` valid?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How is your `createBookingDTO` defined ? I guess if you set all fields in your DTO as optional, the ValidationPipe should not complain anymore. Let us know

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that would probably work, yeah. But it's not what I need: The attributes are not optional if it's a booking. I want to keep the validation of the booking and not weaken it at that point.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not something you can do at "property level", with the way `class-validator` is used by the ValidationPipe. Do you have any specific requirement in splitting your body validation into two DTOs? Because using only one would make your life much simpler (and would still allow using a specific DTO class for `user` and a specific DTO class for `booking`)

Comment: You mean a DTO for the complete body as a combination of user and booking? Right, that would be an option in this particular case.

I would have found the optional body version most elegant, but okay, doesn't seem to be the intended way. 

Thanks for your help!